# Why I don't find jar file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, render.com

I created sample Java spring boot code like this.
**Code**
https://github.com/hardreggaecafe/java_spring_boot_sample

And When I deploy this code to Render.com, it fails. Dockerfile is here.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```

**Error**

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/28.2-android/guava-28.2-android.jar (2.6 MB at 5.8 MB/s)
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] Replacing main artifact /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar with repackaged archive, adding nested dependencies in BOOT-INF/.
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar.original
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] Total time:  17.180 s
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-15T08:44:07Z
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 20.12 [WARNING] The requested profile "prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #11 DONE 20.3s
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #12 [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #12 DONE 0.1s
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #13 exporting to docker image format
Aug 15 05:44:08 PM  #13 exporting layers
Aug 15 05:44:09 PM  #13 exporting layers 1.1s done
Aug 15 05:44:09 PM  #13 exporting manifest sha256:1ed8ee65532237425105db1aae4daf717d2a9a7713ff828eaceb10c126220ee9 done
Aug 15 05:44:09 PM  #13 exporting config sha256:13704bb38ca3dfc2f382ecf143bcf3adccbd4609b81037ceb10138f1197599f6 done
Aug 15 05:44:14 PM  #13 DONE 6.2s
Aug 15 05:44:14 PM  
Aug 15 05:44:14 PM  #14 exporting content cache
Aug 15 05:44:14 PM  #14 preparing build cache for export
Aug 15 05:44:30 PM  #14 DONE 16.4s
Aug 15 05:44:31 PM  Pushing image to registry...
Aug 15 05:44:34 PM  Upload succeeded
Aug 15 05:44:34 PM  DONE
Aug 15 05:44:51 PM  /bin/sh: [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]: not found
Aug 15 05:44:52 PM  /bin/sh: [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]: not found
Aug 15 05:45:08 PM  /bin/sh: [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]: not found
```

I can't figure out
`/bin/sh: [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]: not found`.

I'd appreciate if someone tell me how to fix it.

Comment: *COPY --from=build /target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar* Don't know Docker but there's a space in that path by the looks (which probably would break it) Also (not fatal) *-Pprod -DskipTests* both look wrong [and 1st reported as wrong]. The last is usually `-Dmaven.test.skip=true`

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately, after replacing `RUN mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, it's still same.

Comment: You *did* notice my "not fatal" comment? What else did you change?

Comment: Ah, now I notice your "not fatal". I only replaced 3rd line on Dockerfile.

Comment: Difficult to see definitive docs, but try `cp build/target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar`

Comment: Oh thank you. I'm sure I will.

Comment: @g00se BTW, where should I do cp command?

Comment: @Mar-Z Thanks. So how should I provide it? I'd appreciate if you could show how.

Comment: *use the RUN command for that. RUN cp build/target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar* Did you try that (in place of your current COPY)?

Comment: Check a similar example here: https://dev.to/merkasin/learning-to-deploy-spring-boot-web-application-to-on-renderfree-tier-478m

Comment: Error turns to `[stage-1 2/2] RUN cp build/target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar demo.jar:
cp: can't stat 'build/target/QuickMaster-1.0.0.jar': No such file or directory` Still it's difficult.

Comment: @Mar-Z Oops, is that so? Sorry again, and could you give me how to provide Java command and runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're encountering, seems to be related to the way you're specifying the ENTRYPOINT command in your Dockerfile. The issue likely stems from the use of curly quotes instead of regular double quotes. Docker expects regular double quotes for specifying commands.

Here's your original Dockerfile line causing the issue:

```
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```

Replace the curly quotes with regular double quotes:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "demo.jar"]
```